# Getting a 'source: not found' error when using source in a bash script

Tags: bash, virtualenv

I'm trying to write (what I thought would be) a simple bash script that will:

1. run virtualenv to create a new environment at $1
2. activate the virtual environment
3. do some more stuff (install django, add django-admin.py to the virtualenv's path, etc.)

Step 1 works quite well, but I can't seem to activate the virtualenv. For those not familiar with virtualenv, it creates an `activate` file that activates the virtual environment. From the CLI, you run it using `source`

```
source $env_name/bin/activate
```

Where $env_name, obviously, is the name of the dir that the virtual env is installed in.

In my script, after creating the virtual environment, I store the path to the activate script like this:

```
activate="`pwd`/$ENV_NAME/bin/activate"
```

But when I call `source "$activate"`, I get this:

```
/home/clawlor/bin/scripts/djangoenv: 20: source: not found
```

I know that `$activate` contains the correct path to the activate script, in fact I even test that a file is there before I call `source`. But `source` itself can't seem to find it. I've also tried running all of the steps manually in the CLI, where everything works fine.

In my research I found [this script](http://www.doughellmann.com/articles/CompletelyDifferent-2008-05-virtualenvwrapper/Listing1.html), which is similar to what I want but is also doing a lot of other things that I don't need, like storing all of the virtual environments in a ~/.virtualenv directory (or whatever is in $WORKON_HOME). But it seems to me that he is creating the path to `activate`, and calling `source "$activate"` in basically the same way I am.

Here is the script in its entirety:

```
#!/bin/sh

PYTHON_PATH=~/bin/python-2.6.1/bin/python

if [ $# = 1 ]
then
    ENV_NAME="$1"
    virtualenv -p $PYTHON_PATH --no-site-packages $ENV_NAME
    activate="`pwd`/$ENV_NAME/bin/activate"

    if [ ! -f "$activate" ]
    then
        echo "ERROR: activate not found at $activate"
        return 1
    fi

    source "$activate"
else
    echo 'Usage: djangoenv ENV_NAME'
fi
```

DISCLAIMER: My bash script-fu is pretty weak. I'm fairly comfortable at the CLI, but there may well be some extremely stupid reason this isn't working.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

If you're writing a bash script, call it by name:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

/bin/sh is not guaranteed to be bash. This caused a ton of broken scripts in Ubuntu some years ago (IIRC).

The source builtin works just fine in bash; but you might as well just use dot like Norman suggested.

Comment: This solution was originally a comment in Norman Ramsey's answer. Since this is what actually fixed the problem, I've changed this to be the 'accepted answer'

Comment: So, how do you call bash by name if you were just typing `source ~/.bashrc` before? Do you do `bash ~/.bashrc`?

Answer (score 220):

In the POSIX standard, which `/bin/sh` is supposed to respect, the command is `.` (a single dot), not `source`. The `source` command is a `csh`-ism that has been pulled into `bash`.

Try

```
. $env_name/bin/activate
```

Or if you must have non-POSIX `bash`-isms in your code, use `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: That fixes it. (changing /bin/sh to /bin/bash). For some reason the environment is not activated in the CLI when the script finishes, but that's a minor problem.

Comment: According to the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-source) `source` is a synonym for `.`.

Comment: I came across this when using a docker container with entrypoint like this, `/bin/sh -c '/path/to/script.sh'`. Even though my script was a bash script, source failed to source the exports. But "." worked!

Comment: This fixed it for me - testing my .sh in the shell was working with source, but failing in Jenkins.  Changing source to a dot worked in the shell and most importantly, worked in Jenkins too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

In Ubuntu if you execute the script with `sh scriptname.sh` you get this problem.

Try executing the script with `./scriptname.sh` instead.

Comment: i got a segmentation fault when doing this.

Comment: File must be executable: `chmod +x filename.sh`

Comment: Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 1):

best to add the **full path** of the file you intend to source.

eg

`source ./.env` instead of `source .env`

or  `source /var/www/html/site1/.env`

Answer (score 0):

After multiple attempts I found below. Simply do

$ `./env_name/bin/activate`