# multiple commands in a notebook cell to activate virtual env

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter, virtual-environment

I am using `Jupyter Notebook` and the `present working directory` is `home/abcde`.

However, I want the virtual environment use `python 3` interpreter and directory be created under the below path

`!mkdir python-virtual-environments && cd python-virtual-environments && virtualenv env && virtualenv -p python3 env && .python-virtual-environments/env/bin/activate`

Here, instead of the `source` keyword, I have to use `.` based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670191/getting-a-source-not-found-error-when-using-source-in-a-bash-script)

However, I am getting the below error.

```
 re/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)
 activators PythonActivator,FishActivator,XonshActivator,CShellActivator,PowerShellActivator,BashActivator
/bin/sh: 1: .python-virtual-environments/env/bin/activate: not found   #error is here in this line.
```

Can you help on how can I execute this command?

If I break down the commands and put them in each cell, the folders are being created in the `pwd` which is `home/abcde`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you're already in the `env` directory, and then you're executing `.python-virtual-environments/env/bin/activate`.

You need to run `. env/bin/activate` as follows:

```
!mkdir python-virtual-environments && cd python-virtual-environments && virtualenv env && virtualenv -p python3 env && . env/bin/activate
```

> If I break down the commands and put them in each cell, the folders are being created in the pwd which is home/abcde

It's because each terminal command (using `!`) is executed in a new shell. So, `cd python-virtual-environments` becomes useless, you can instead use `%cd python-virtual-environments/` if you want to run each command independently or use `%%bash`.

```
%%bash

mkdir python-virtual-environments
cd python-virtual-environments
virtualenv -p python3 env
. env/bin/activate
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try solving it.