# How to create and activate virtualenv at the same time in my bash shell script

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I'm trying to create an automation program that setups my django project.

I was able to create the project folder and virtual environment however I'm not sure if virtual env was activated or not in that folder. I need the virtual env to activate so that I can install django. The way I run the command for now is `./auto.sh setup <poject_folder_name>`, where setup is the name of my function. Here is the inside of the function.

```
python3 setup.py $2
cd $FILEPATH/$2
echo $FILEPATH/$2
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
  
cd ~/scripts
python3 checker.py
```

The last two lines in the above code is my attempt in checking if the virtual env was activated in that folder and I always get the `FAILED` output. This is what `checker.py` contains.

```
import sys

if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
    print('\nOK\n')
else:
    print('\nFAILED\n')
```

I'm really new to bash scripting and any help is greatly appreciated.

[EDIT] FILEPATH was set in my .bash_profile to the directory where I want the new folder to be created.

Comment: You activated the virtual environment globally; your current working directory doesn't have any affect on whether it is activated or not. There isn't really anything *to* check.

Comment: Sorry as I wasnt clear the first time. I have edited my post which would explain `FILEPATH`

Comment: Are you sure it's a bash script? [Set bash shebang explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/670216/7976758). May be anything here help: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbash%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+activate+from+script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution 1, using a prefix

```sh
VENV="env/bin"
PYTHON="$VENV/python"
# etc...
```

## Solution 2, using a function

```sh
activate () {
    . `pwd`/env/bin/activate
}

activate
# etc...
```